# Signal in and out of flip according to IEEE symbols

Tags: flipflop, waveform

I have the following IEEE symbol for a SR flip-flop
[image]

I have to work out the waveforms W and X given A and B. Here are A, B and the associated solution for W and X (as given by the book):

[image]

From my understanding of IEEE symbols the following rules apply:

1. If S1 is asserted then I should make W = 1 and then X will get a value according to the truth table of a SR flip flop.
2. If R2 is asserted then I should make X = 0 and W will get a value according to the truth table of a SR flip flop
3. If both S1 and R2 are asserted then I should make W = 1 and X = 0
4. If neither S1 nor R2 are asserted then I should just use the truth table of SR flip flop to determine W and X.

However I'm having some issues understanding the solution as at the beginning both S1 and R2 are asserted yet both W and X seem to be 1.

Where am I going wrong with my assumptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you are making is that the inputs are inverted.

In the IEEE Std 91/91a-1991 rectangular shape standard, a half triangle on the top of a pin indicates that the signal is inverted.

For example, this is a single bit inverter. Notice the triangle on the output indicating inversion:

[image: IEEE Inverter Symbol]

<sup>[Image Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate)</sup>

The same thing applies to inputs. Notice how the Load input is inverted in this symbol:

[image]

<sup>[Image Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate)</sup>

So basically in your symbol, S and R are active low signals, i.e. they are considered "asserted" when they are low.